# How to use Selecium on Angular App for integration test

Tags: angular, selenium, testing, protractor

I am new in the world of testing.
I would like to test e2e my front-end part (Back : Spring Boot, Front : Angular 11).
I have a lot of questions :

1. Is Selenium & Protractor are the same ?
2. How to set up Selenium on my Angular App ?

I read a lot of article and for angular app many developers are using Protractor or Cypress.
In my project, I must use Selenium, I don't know what to do :(
I would like a clear explanation about testing Angular App (not AngularJs) using Selenium.

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q.** Is Selenium & Protractor are the same ?

**Ans:** No, they are not.

Protractor is an `end-to-end test framework` for **Angular** and **AngularJS** `applications`. `Protractor` runs tests against your application running in a `real browser`, interacting with it as a user would.

**Whereas Selenium:**

**Selenium automates browsers. That's it!**
What you do with that power is entirely up to you.

Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes but is certainly not limited to just that.

**Q.** How to set up Selenium on my Angular App?

**Ans:** Since you've mentioned that selenium is must for you to use.

I would say first determine the binding language first, it could be:

1. Java
2. Python
3. Javascript
4. Ruby
5. VBA

etc. understand that you can integrate your selenium script to any binding language of your choice (also depends on your company, policy, etc.)

**Conclusion:**

You can use any one of them based on your need/requirement/knowledge, but `Protractor` is a framework where as Selenium is just a functional tool.

Also, `Selenium` has large user support than  `Protractor`

[Link](https://www.testbytes.net/blog/protractor-vs-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not correct, it should be focused on 1 specific question, not 3.
Anyway, I will try answering here.
So,

1. No, Selenium and Protractor are not the same, these are different automation tools. There are a lot articles about [selenium vs protractor](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+vs+protractor&oq=dselenium+vs+pr&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i13l3j0i13i30l2j0i22i30l4.9711j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
2. Selenium [can be used](selenium for angularjs application) for testing Angular applications. There are a lot of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380994/can-angularjs-apps-be-automated-with-selenium-if-yes-why-should-we-use-protrac) and [articles](https://blog.vsoftconsulting.com/blog/testing-angular-applications-using-selenium) about this as well.
3. You can easily find how to [setup selenium for angularjs application](https://www.google.com/search?q=setup+selenium+for+angularjs+application&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFgKrD0a71AhVcgv0HHWK8CCMQBSgAegQIARAy&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1).

What tool is preferable for testing Angular js application Selenium or Protractor?
It would be opinion based question.
There are people who would prefer utilizing Selenium while others would prefer Protractor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still don't understand all the article are talking about implementation using Protector. I watch one tutorial which they use Java to do test on Angular App. Why they don't use Angular Framework to do e2e test ?

Comment: I'm not the author of those articles... Possibly it would be more suitable to use Protractor (not a Protector) to test Angular JS apps, however this can be done with Selenium too as well